# GeoServer : insert custom properties in SLD XML file

Tags: xml, filter, geoserver, sld

I need to allow the visitors of my site to filter the data shown on an OpenLayer map. Basically, I generate SLD files from a CSV dataset and want to let the user the ability to filter the data of each column of the dataset.

To do so, I want to compare what are the selected filters with what's in the SLD file in order to generate a temporary SLD file for the user to give to OpenLayer to display.

Would you know any way of inserting these customs values into the rules of the full SLD that is generated from the dataset ? So that I can then go through this full SLD and be able to pick only the rules  that I need according to what the user selected as filters?

Thank you for your help.
Regards;

Comment: Do you have a specific set of filters or is each one different?

Comment: I am not sure to understand but I have the same set of custom properties per rule (and same set for one layer). I want to be able to insert them into each rule in the XML SLD so that I can later, in my app, generate a new set of rules in a new temp SLD after going through them and scratching the one that the filter don't match. I tried using multiple `<PropertyIsEqualTo>` but I seems it would keep only one. What's your take on that?

Comment: Use and or or to join filters